# Guava's Sets.Intersection method misbehaving

Tags: java, guava

I have a scenario where in, i need to find intersection of two sets based on a specific  field(only color in this case) from the objects contained in the set.

Hence I am trying to find a intersection, subtraction of two Sets(which use a comparator that uses the color of the object to decide on equality of 2 car objects) by using google's Guava. But strangely A intersection B is not equal to  B intersection A.

Please help me find where it is going wrong.
why is A intersection B not equal to  B intersection A? I am interested in intersection part only.

```
   public class Car {

   public String id;
     public String color;
   public String getId() {
          return id;
   }
   public void setId(String id) {
          this.id = id;
   }
   public String getColor() {
          return color;
   }
   public void setColor(String color) {
          this.color = color;
   }


   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
          final int prime = 31;
          int result = 1;
          result = prime * result + ((color == null) ? 0 : color.hashCode());
          result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
          return result;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          if (this == obj)
                 return true;
          if (obj == null)
                 return false;
          if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                 return false;
          Car other = (Car) obj;
          if (color == null) {
                 if (other.color != null)
                       return false;
          } else if (!color.equals(other.color))
                 return false;
          if (id == null) {
                 if (other.id != null)
                       return false;
          } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                 return false;
          return true;
   }
   public Car(String id, String color) {
          super();
          this.id = id;
          this.color = color;
   }
   public Car() {
          super();
   }


  }

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;


 public class Tester {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

          final Set<Car> first = new TreeSet<Car>( new Comparator<Car> (){
                 public int compare( final Car o1, final Car o2 ){
                  return comp(o1.getColor(), o2.getColor() );  
              }
          } );
          first.add(new Car("1","blue"));
          first.add(new Car("2","green"));
          first.add(new Car("3","red"));

          final Set<Car> second = new TreeSet<Car>( new Comparator<Car> (){
                 public int compare( final Car o3, final Car o4 ){
                  return comp1(o3.getColor(), o4.getColor() );  
              }
          } );
          second.add(new Car("4","black"));
          second.add(new Car("5","green"));
          second.add(new Car("6","blue"));
          second.add(new Car("7","red"));

          final Set<Car> intersection1 = Sets.intersection( first, second );
          System.out.println("intersection1 size = "+intersection1.size());
          for(Car carr : intersection1){
                 System.out.println("carr.id ="+carr.id+" carr.color ="+carr.color);
          }
          System.out.println();
          final Set<Car> intersection2 = Sets.intersection( second, first);
          System.out.println("intersection2 size = "+intersection2.size());
          for(Car carr : intersection2){
                 System.out.println("carr.id ="+carr.id+" carr.color ="+carr.color);
          }
          System.out.println();

          final Set<Car> Pure1 = Sets.difference(first, second);
          System.out.println("Pure1 size = "+Pure1.size());
          for(Car carr : Pure1){
                 System.out.println("carr.id ="+carr.id+" carr.color ="+carr.color);
          }
          System.out.println();

          final Set<Car> Pure2 = Sets.difference(second, first);
          System.out.println("Pure2 size = "+Pure2.size());
          for(Car carr : Pure2){
                 System.out.println("carr.id ="+carr.id+" carr.color ="+carr.color);
          }
          System.out.println();

    }
    static int comp(String a, String b ){
          if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
                 return 0;
          }
          else 
                 return 1;
   }
   static int comp1(String a, String b ){
          if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
                 return 0;
          }
          else 
                 return 1;
   }

 }
```

Output :

```
intersection1 size = 3
carr.id =1 carr.color =blue
carr.id =2 carr.color =green
carr.id =3 carr.color =red

intersection2 size = 2
carr.id =5 carr.color =green
carr.id =7 carr.color =red

Pure1 size = 0

Pure2 size = 2
carr.id =4 carr.color =black
 carr.id =6 carr.color =blue
```

Comment: You need to show the contents of each set and then the output. Note that "intersection" isn't the same thing as "subtraction".

Comment: I know "intersection" isn't the same thing as "subtraction". Tht's y asking for Intersection only.  No need to downVote

Comment: I didn't downvote, because I think the question can be salvaged, but we need the actual and expected results.

Comment: There is no need of DownVote bcoz question is valid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementations of `comp` are incorrect, and your comparators don't satisfy their contracts, so you can get undefined and unpredictable behavior from `TreeSet`.  This has nothing to do with Guava's `Sets.intersection` method.

The spec for `Comparator.compare` says:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

...which your `Comparator`s don't do.

The easiest fix would probably be to use

```
new Comparator<Car>(){
    public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
        return o1.getColor().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getColor());
    }
}
```